# Show $f([0, 1])$ has zero measure

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

We are given that $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m$ where $m > 1$ is continuously differentiable once.

We want to show that $f(\mathbb R)$ has measure zero.

**What I did:**

Notice that $\mathbb R = \cup_{n \in \mathbb Z}[n, n+1]$, so $f(\mathbb R) = f(\cup_{n \in \mathbb Z}[n, n+1]) = \cup_{n \in \mathbb Z} f([n, n+1])$

This is a countable union, and so if we show that $f([n, n+1])$ has measure zero, we can infer that $f(\mathbb R)$ has measure zero.

Without loss of generality, we can prove that $f([0, 1])$ has measure zero.

But how do we do that? We don't know anything about $f$ other then it's continuous with continuous derivatives. We don't know what $f([0, 1])$ is or how to cover it with arbitrarily small cubes.

Comment: I would argue that $f(\mathbb R)$ is a curve and since f ist cont. differentiable $f(\mathbb R)$ is a one dimensional submanifold in $\mathbb R^n, \ n > 1$. So $f(\mathbb R)$ has measure zero.

Comment: @House Not necessarily a submanifold. It could self intersect (like $(x^2, x^3 - x)$, for instance) or have cusps (like $(x^2, x^3)$).

Comment: @House I understand the intuition, but I don't know how to formalize it as a proof with the definition of a measure.

Comment: This is true when $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous; differentiability is not necessary. First consider the restriction of $f$ to $[-N,N]^m$, then use the fact that $$\mathbb R^m = \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty [-N,N]^m. $$

Comment: @Math1000: you probably didn't mean it this way, but differentiability (as opposed to continuous differentiability) is neither a weaker nor stronger condition than Lipschitz. The result holds in either case though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists $L$ such that $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^m$ is $L$-Lipschitz in the sup norm, i.e.
$$||f(x)-f(y)||_\infty=\max_i|f(x)_i-f(y)_i|\leq L|x-y|.$$
This means that the image of an interval $[a-r,a+r]$ is contained in the set $\{x\mid \|x-f(a)\|_\infty\leq Lr\}$, which has measure at most $(2Lr)^m:$

$$\mu(f([a-r,a+r])) \leq (2Lr)^m$$

where $\mu$ is Lebesgue outer measure (or even just Jordan outer measure). Hence for any $n\geq 1,$ setting $r=1/2n,$

$$\mu(f([0,1]))=\mu(f([0,1/n]\cup [1/n,2/n] \cup \cdots \cup [(n-1)/n,1])) \leq n(L/n)^m = L^mn^{1-m}.$$
Taking $n\to\infty$ gives $\mu(f[0,1])=0.$